# How can I programmatically remove a specific image from a PDF document?

Tags: java, pdf

Is it possible to remove a *specific* image from a PDF document?

I've found a few articles around the web which talk about removing/replacing *all* images from a PDF, or even removing the first image on the first page of a PDF. So far, though, I haven't been able to find any examples for removing a specific image in a targeted fashion.

I'm not familiar with PDF manipulation - is there a way to name/tag/identify a specific image object embedded in a PDF? If so, it seems that we could somehow find the image using this identifier.

I'm using Java. I've found several libraries for PDF manipulation, each slightly different.. any recommendations for a good library to use in this situation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If it THE SINGLE PDF document in your life in which you want to hide/switch off/delete image, you can do it by your fingers exactly in the body of the document. Open it in the text editor, find the page, find the page content, resource, and change width and height parameters:

```
17 0 obj
<< /ProcSet [ /PDF /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] /ColorSpace << /Cs1 7 0 R >>
/ExtGState << /Gs1 11 0 R >> /XObject << /Im1 18 0 R >> >>
endobj
18 0 obj
<< /Length 19 0 R /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Width 886 /Height 717 /Interpolate
true /ColorSpace 20 0 R /Intent /Perceptual /SMask 21 0 R /BitsPerComponent
8 /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
xÏΩ T◊∂>æYÔ∑^c¢ôníóó˜ø◊17ä‚ê®h¢WÅDççF„’DLà(TúMçÇI�p�IïA2(¢B3è"≥}# ˆµªˇ_’È™ÆÆ:
```

Change `/Width 886 /Height 717` with `/Width 000 /Height 000` in any hex editor you have and the image will disappears.

IMPORTANT!
The PDF file structure offsets is strictly calculated, therefore, it is important use quantity of zeroes the same as original numbers.

In case you have plans to do the same operation with tons of files, I can not help you, sorry!

Comment: Actually it is not exactly removing the image, because this method is not the downsizing of the document. Another words it is the image hiding method.

Comment: Hi, you don't need to use comments to add more info to your answer - edit your answer instead `:)`